# Where to place the JavaScript in SharePoint Foundation 2010's list form?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

We are new to SharePoint 2010 so we just wanted to ask these questions.

1. We are using SharePoint Designer 2010 for editing a list form (NewForm, EditForm and DispForm) in SharePoint Foundation 2010. From the block of codes behind a form, where should we exactly place the JavaScript or the JavaScript function (maybe a place before or after a certain tag)?
2. I heard we can also insert the script on a Content Editor Web Part. Will it be the same if we are going to place it on the code behind the form?
3. How to properly make a function call in the code behind the form? Let say on a button click. Can you give an example code?
4. Also, is it possible make a function call by creating a script in notepad, saving it in the Shared Document library and referencing the source of the script in the code that you will place behind the form or in the Content Editor Web Part?

Thank You,

Arnel

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the script in every page you can call it directly in the masterpage v4.master

If you will use it just in a particular page use it on a Content Editor Web Part and you can call it in the same way

I recommend you to store the extra js files under _catalogs, make sure you always check in the script otherwise it only will be visible for the user that upload/changed it